# XE6 - How to convert TStringStream content to TStream?

Tags: delphi

I am using following code to convert a TStringStream to a TStream. But it give error when I try to copy the TStringStream's content to TStream.

It seems I am making some very obvious mistake but am not able to catch it.

My Code:

```
procedure TfrmMain2.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
var
  SS:TStringStream;
  S, S2:TStream;
  PhotoStr: String;
begin
  PhotoStr := 'Hello World, Testing: /9j/4AAQSkZJRgABAQAAAQABAAD//' +
     'gA7Q1JFQVRPUjogZ2QtanBlZyB2MS4wICh1c2luZyBJSkcgSlBFRyB2NjIp' +
     'LCBxdWFsaXR5ID0gODUK/9sAQwAFAwQEBAMFBAQEBQUFBgcMCAcHBwcPCwsJ' +
     'DBEPEhIRDxERExYcFxMUGhURERghGBodHR8fHxMXIiQiHiQcHh8e';

  SS := TStringStream.Create(PhotoStr);
  S := TStream.Create();
  S.CopyFrom(SS, SS.Size);  //<= This line gives error
end;
```

The error message I am getting is: ...class EWriteError with message 'Stream write error'.

I don't know as to why I am getting this error.

Comment: A word of advice, always include the error message in a question like this. And include it verbatim, don't describe it. There's usually information to be found in an error message. Don't ignore their content.

Comment: Your example doesn't do anything with S. If your actual code you use S with, takes a value of type TStream, it will accept a value of type TStringStream as well, since TStringStream inherits from TStream.

Comment: @StijnSanders, I have not provided the whole code. The last line itself gives error and stops there. I have noted that with a comment.

Comment: A TStringStream *is* a TStream, so taken literally, there is no 'conversion' required. You probably intend a TMemoryStream instead, though even then, TStringStream is a TMemoryStream descendant.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are creating an instance of `TStream` which is an abstract class. You must never instantiate `TStream` directly. Always instantiate a descendent class instead, such as `TFileStream`, `TMemoryStream`, etc.